# largestChangeId smaller than the last item's id?

Tags: google-drive-api

I moved three files in My Drive to the trash. Then retrieved changes with Changes: list API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list). It returned three changes, with ids 11607, 11608 and 11609. However, the largestChangeId field was 11608. When I made the API request again with startChangeId: 11608, it returned the two last changes. When I made the API request with startChangeId: 11609, it returned no result.

Is it expected? Or relying on change ids in such a way is not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it looks like you're exposed to a bug. I'm adding details of the changes list and how it should work in normal circumstances. Let's assume your latest change id was `11606` and you made three trashing operations.

`GET changes?startChangeId=11607` should list:

- 11607
- 11608
- 11609

And the next time you are requesting changes.list, you should always increment the latest `latestChangeId` by 1.

In this case you need to request the following on your next poll.

`GET changes?startChangeID=11610` and it will be returning an empty list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will the bug be fixed?